# Parse RGB string to integers and avoid "non-well formed numeric value encountered" in Laravel SimpleQrcode

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code, text-parsing, rgba

I am working on SimpleQrcode Laravel.
I'm trying to store color in rgba format(ajax) in database for a specific id's qrcode's background color and calling it as a variable to change the qr-code's bgcolor. I cannot use hex format because simpleqrcode dependency only accepts rgba format.

So I have stored rgba in database and when I call it to the controller it shows me the error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered.

Further I researched that when I call colors from database it comes with quotations by default and I tried to replace it with `str_replace()` but that didn't work.

This is my code:

```
public function qrcode($id){
      $article = Article::find($id);
      $rgba = $article->bgcolor;
      $html = str_replace('"', '', $rgba);

      $image_path = \QrCode::format('png')
          // ->merge('../storage/app/public/'.$article->image, .15, true)
          ->size(200)

          ->backgroundColor($html)
          ->errorCorrection('H')


          ->generate('127.0.0.1:8000/articles/'.$article->id , '../public/Qrcodes'.$article->image);
          // dd($article->bgcolor);
          // $image = '../public/'.$article->image;

      return view('articles.modify_qrcode', compact('article'));
```

[image: error]

[image: error]

Somebody told me to update composer. I have already updated it.

Comment: What the content of the value `bgcolor` ?

Comment: rgba format of a color

Comment: So you have a content like `#ffffff` Is that correct?

Comment: dd($html); result: "135, 56, 56"

Comment: because the dependency do not accept hex format i stored rgba format like 0,0,0 but it shows this error

Comment: then i tried to check and hard coded the rgba value with quotations then it throws the same error... so in my opinion the default quotations around the rendered value is interfering in code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment;
`dd($html); result: "135, 56, 56"`

You code

```php
$rgba = $article->bgcolor;
$html = str_replace('"', '', $rgba);
```

Will create the variable `$html` with the string value `"135,56,56"`
But you need 3 integer variables `$red`, `$green` and `$blue`  since `backgroundColor(int $red, int $green, int $blue, ?int $alpha = null)` take 3 colors separately.

What you can do is;

```
$article = Article::find($id);
list($red, $green, $blue) = array_map('intval', explode(',', $article->bgcolor));

$image_path = \QrCode::format('png')
              ->size(200)
              ->backgroundColor($red, $green, $blue)
              ->errorCorrection('H')
              ->generate('127.0.0.1:8000/articles/'.$article->id , '../public/Qrcodes'.$article->image);
```

Explanation:

- `explode(',', $article->bgcolor)` Will transform the **string** `"135, 56, 56"` into an **array of string**: [`"123"`, `"56"` and `"56"`]
- `array_map('intval', [])` Will iterate through the **array of string** to cast them into an **array of int** : [`"123"`, `"56"` and `"56"`] will become [`123`, `56` and `56`]
- `list($red, $green, $blue)` will assign the **array** values into each variables; `$red`, `$green` and `$blue`

Comment: Notice; `explode(', ', $article->bgcolor)`  I edited to remove the extra "space" char. since `intval` will ignore it, but you will encounter issue if some colors doesn't have this space.

Answer (score 0):

The best, most direct way to parse RBG or RBGA strings is with `sscanf()`.  This will not only extract the desired values from the strictly formatted string, it will ignore whitespaces, allow for the optional existence of the alpha value, and cast all values to integer or float types as designated.

Concerningly, the method signature for `backgroundColor()` in your application receives the `alpha` parameter as a nullable integer, but it should certainly accept float type values.

For your precise scenario, you can implement the call without declaring individual variables, then simply unpack the flat array of integers as method patameters for `backgroundColor()`:

```
->backgroundColor(
    ...sscanf(
        $article->bgcolor,
        '%d,%d,%d,%d' // or add double quotes: '"%d,%d,%d,%d"'
    )
)
```

Here is a script with some test cases to show you how it works. (Notice the `%f`)  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/pio7p)

```
$tests = [
    '12, 34, 56',
    '233, 0, 0, 1',
    '99, 68, 135',
    '0, 0, 0, 0.31',
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    unset($r, $g, $b, $a);
    sscanf($test, '%d,%d,%d,%f', $r, $g, $b, $a);
    var_dump($r, $g, $b, $a);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
int(12)
int(34)
int(56)
NULL

int(233)
int(0)
int(0)
float(1)

int(99)
int(68)
int(135)
NULL

int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
float(0.31)
```